# Making a decision tree with string variables

Tags: r, string, decision-tree

I'm trying to make a decision tree from a data set with songs and various attributes about them (genre, tempo, etc). Out of these attributes, all except the genre are numerical values. I already know how to make a decision tree using only the numerical values, but I want to add genres to the tree too. However, decision trees don't like strings.

I've tried using `as.factor` on the Genre column but the results are less than ideal. With as.factor, there is a mysterious genre in my decision tree named "cefjkm". I thought that maybe I could look at the dataset's genre, assuming `as.factor` had changed the values. However, they were still their original words in the dataset.

Then I tried using `as.numerical` after `as.factor`. However, numbers aren't much better. It is unsurprisingly treating them as if they were actual numbers, thus giving strange nodes like "Genre < 4.5".

I also tried using `factor(...)`, but even after reading the documentation, I'm not quite sure how to use it. Using the data set where I simply changed the genres to a factor (the one that gave me cefjkm), I wrote this, using only two genres as test values:

```
factor(data_set_test1, levels=c("rap","rock"))
```

This simply resulted in all the genres that were not "rap" or "rock" being replaced with NAs. I believe my biggest issue is that I don't understand what a level is in this context. When using just `as.factor`, it makes a level for each individual genre, but I do not know what difference that makes or if I can take advantage of it.

Ideally, I'd like for the genres to not be numerical and instead say what genre they are, instead of names like "cefjkm". If that's not possible, then I want to see the `as.factor` version of the genres so I can compare them to the original column of strings. I'd like to see what strange name each genre was given.

EDIT
For help, I made a subset of the data with 25 songs instead of 200:

```
MGSHelp2 <- data.frame(
  Genre = factor(
    c(
      "rap", "pop", "covertronica", "country", "pop", "pop", "rock",
      "pop", "pop", "pop", "rap", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rap", "pop",
      "pop", "pop", "pop", "rock", "pop", "rock", "country", "pop",
      "pop"
    ),
    levels = c(
      "aussietronica", "bath indie", "big room", "boy band", "brostep",
      "chillwave", "classic anime", "classical", "contemporary r&b",
      "country", "covertronica", "disco", "edm", "funk carioca", "hip hop",
      "pop", "rap", "reggae fusion", "rock"
    )
  ),
  Danceability = c(
    0.831, 0.688, 0.854, 0.652, 0.463, 0.38, 0.436, 0.528, 0.326, 0.47, 0.909,
    0.429, 0.447, 0.502, 0.67, 0.751, 0.586, 0.578, 0.724, 0.806, 0.694, 0.66,
    0.392, 0.593, 0.621
  ),
  Energy = c(
    0.727, 0.582, 0.806, 0.767, 0.268, 0.325, 0.978, 0.923, 0.528, 0.793, 0.541,
    0.974, 0.967, 0.966, 0.424, 0.834, 0.616, 0.574, 0.491, 0.437, 0.891, 0.462,
    0.37, 0.781, 0.539
  ),
  Speechiness = c(
    0.169, 0.0542, 0.0886, 0.0372, 0.0408, 0.0328, 0.201, 0.058, 0.032, 0.26,
    0.497, 0.0899, 0.0793, 0.0946, 0.292, 0.0437, 0.0324, 0.0454, 0.0296, 0.191,
    0.0949, 0.103, 0.0298, 0.0545, 0.0788
  ),
  Acousticness = c(
    0.447, 0.23, 0.0209, 0.0355, 0.981, 0.712, 6.9e-05, 0.00536, 0.159, 0.164,
    0.322, 0.00168, 0.00448, 0.00575, 0.333, 0.3, 0.182, 0.196, 0.018, 0.0279,
    0.0562, 0.168, 0.205, 0.000724, 0.675
  ),
  Instrumentalness = c(
    0, 0.000157, 0.0542, 6.92e-06, 0.00659, 0, 6.08e-05, 1.46e-05, 3.55e-05,
    1.31e-06, 0, 0, 0, 1.56e-06, 0, 1.77e-05, 0, 0, 1.29e-05, 0, 0, 1.37e-06,
    0.0096, 0, 1.25e-05
  ),
  Liveness = c(
    0.111, 0.0663, 0.0703, 0.397, 0.185, 0.0997, 0.148, 0.134, 0.0862, 0.313,
    0.0942, 0.164, 0.487, 0.117, 0.112, 0.355, 0.0927, 0.083, 0.0887, 0.457,
    0.561, 0.486, 0.0821, 0.225, 0.125
  ),
  Valence = c(
    0.703, 0.872, 0.637, 0.73, 0.109, 0.429, 0.103, 0.267, 0.289, 0.216, 0.823,
    0.33, 0.606, 0.638, 0.743, 0.894, 0.719, 0.301, 0.383, 0.803, 0.563, 0.384,
    0.512, 0.565, 0.202
  ),
  Tempo = c(
    125.068, 85.486, 124.927, 132.017, 112.695, 89.898, 155.98, 130.067, 166.213,
    170.1, 135.106, 110.373, 179.991, 159.948, 77.685, 95.053, 148.088, 174.152,
    105.046, 114.918, 97.939, 167.098, 48.718, 103.025, 81.967
  ),
  Pref2 = factor(c(
    "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Bad",
    "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad",
    "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Bad"
  ))
)
```

Libraries: tidyverse, tree, randomForest, rpart
I'm not actually sure any of the libraries except tree are necessary. I added randomForest and rpart just in case tree on its own cannot help me here.

This example dataset was made from a version of the full data set where I had already done `as.factor(df$genre)`, but if necessary, I can provide a version from before `as.factor`.

Also, here's how I tried `as.numeric`:

```
MGSHelp3<-MGSHelp2
MGSHelp3$Genre<-as.numeric(MGSHelp3$Genre)
```

I don't want to clog this question up, but I can add the `dput` version of this if necessary.

Comment: it would helpful for people who can help if they can get glimpse of your data you can do this by using `dput(df)`

Comment: Welcome to SO Me Me. It will be much easier to answer your question if it is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please run `dput(data_set_test1)` and copy the result into your question. Also, add the code you are running and any packages (libraries) you are using so that others can see you issue better. Thanks

Comment: If you've got a reasonable number of levels (strings are repeated across rows such that every observation isn't unique), trees can be made with strings, e.g. [lightgbm](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R/reference/lgb.Dataset.set.categorical.html) is well known for handling categorical data well (though that makes gradient boosted trees, not individual decision trees). What are you using to make trees?